# Post increment of index in a string in c++

Tags: c++, string, combinations, post-increment

This is a function that generates all possible strings with different combinations of characters in a given string, and for the generated strings if their length is equal to the specified length in function argument return these strings in a set.
Code 1 works fine, whereas code 2 has one line of change that changes index (post-increment) inside the string after concatenation but this operation causes a different output. The way I thought was that comb string will be concatenated with the desired value of s[i] even when I am using s[i++] because of post-increment, but the behavior is different. Can anyone help with the correct reason for this behavior?

```
code 1:
set<string> generate_comb(string s,int len)
{
    set<string> hold;
    int mask = 1<<s.length();
    for(int no=1;no<mask;no++)
    {
        int num = no;
        int i = 0;
        string comb = "";
        while(num)
        {
            if(num&1)
                comb = comb + s[i];
            num = num>>1;
            i++;
        }
        if(comb.length()==len)
            hold.insert(comb);
    }
    return hold;
}

code 2:
set<string> generate_comb(string s,int len)
{
    set<string> hold;
    int mask = 1<<s.length();
    for(int no=1;no<mask;no++)
    {
        int num = no;
        int i = 0;
        string comb = "";
        while(num)
        {
            if(num&1)
                comb = comb + s[i++]; //this line has been changed 
            num = num>>1;
            //i++;
        }
        if(comb.length()==len)
            hold.insert(comb);
    }
    return hold;
}
```

Comment: Tip: Use `const string&` as arguments to avoid excessive copying. Also `num >>= 1`.

Comment: If you step through in a debugger do you see the difference?

Comment: You may want to reframe as `for (int i = 0; num; ++i)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is the `if`:

```
if(num&1)
    comb = comb + s[i];
num = num>>1;
i++;
```

If the condition is true, concatenate strings and then do the rest *regardless* of the condition.

```
if(num&1)
    comb = comb + s[i++];
num = num>>1;
```

If the condition is true, concatenate and increment, but if the condition is false *no increment happens*.